# How to add nuxt icon from script setup to the body of vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, icons

i am using vuejs with nuxt in which i am using nuxt-icon for icons
i have a component which renders data from the backend and return the it to the page.Now i have some bash code in that and for that bash code i want to add a icon at the top right. Its a SSR so some times the component have bash and some times not so i want to add the icons to all the bash inside the component.

i have created a function to check for all the pre tags and based on that add a button to that its as below

```
onMounted(() => {
  const bashes = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
  bashes.forEach((bash) => {
    if (navigator.clipboard) {
      const wrapperDiv = document.createElement("div");
      bash.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapperDiv, bash);
      wrapperDiv.appendChild(bash);      
      const button = document.createElement("button");
      button.classList.add("absolute","top-8","right-4","text-white","border-1","p-2");
      button.innerText = "copy";
      wrapperDiv.appendChild(button);
      button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
        await copyCode(bash, button);
        button.innerText = "copied!";
        button.classList.add("!text-green-500");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

now i want to replace the copy text with the copy icon from the nuxt-icon